# Representations of elements in polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am reading a paper by Banaschewski ([Krull implies Zorn](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/malq.19940400405)) and I am trying to prove everything I find in order to understand it fully. There's a few facts he states before getting into the actual proof, about the polynomial ring $R=\mathbb{Q}[E]$, where $E$ is an arbitrary set of indeterminates. The first two are:

(1) Since the monomials in the elements of $E$ form a vector space basis of $R$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, any non-zero $a\in R$ has a unique representation $$a=r_1w_1+\ldots+r_nw_n$$ with nonzero $r_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ and distinct monomials $w_i$. The latter will be called the *a-monomials*.

(2) If $a=u_1x_1+\ldots+u_nx_n $ for $u_i\in R$ and $x_i \in E$ then each a-monomial is a multiple of some $x_i$.

(1) is fine, the problem lies in (2). I have tried substituting each of the $u_i$ expressions with their unique representations, and also comparing the unique representation of $a$ with one like in (2), but I get stuck quickly.

Comment: I think what it is saying is actually much simpler than what you think. The $a$-monomials are just the $u_ix_i$ for each $i$ which is clearly a multiple of $x_i$.